# Why are repartition and coalesce slow in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I made RDD which need to be saved as text file (.csv).
since it's work in parallel, output file is as many as work's number.
I though that using "repatition or coalesce" after making RDD would make output as one file.

```
myRDDData.repatition(1).saveAsTextFile(..path)
or
myRDDData.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(..path)
```

It works well BUT so slow to use it.

I just need command like "cat * > output" in shell.
Any idea of this? thanks.

Comment: You are shuffling all the data around which creates network traffic and also you are fetching all the data to the driver which may overwhelm the driver !

Comment: Does coalesce(1) collect all the data in the driver? if so how is it different than collect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question from the title: `repartition` and `coalesce` are slow because they shuffle the data around, data movement is slow. `coalesce` will usually be faster since it allows only reducing the number of partition, so Spark doesn't have to move all the data (it saves as many partitions as you want it to and just moves around the remaining ones).

To answer your problem. There are a few options:

1) the repartition/coalesce to 1, which you are doing. Note here: be careful not to create new RDDs after that and use them since that can cause problems (RDDs up the stream might also have only 1 partition because of that)

2) if your resulting data is small enough and the driver node can handle it in memory you can `myRDDData.collect()` and then use standard Scala/Java APIs to save it to a file

3) do `myRDDData.saveAsTextFile(path)` and then use Java/Scala APIs to merge the files, how you do it depends on the target FS but they probably give you some kind of an API to do so. For example in HDFS you can use [FileUtils.copyMerge()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I would disagree with the statement that `coalesce` allows only reducing number of partitions. Using this function you can also increase number of partitions but in this case you have to set `shuffle` parameter to true. But indeed this operation may be useful if you want to decrease number of partitions without shuffle. For example, in case if initial number of partitions is a factor of target number of partitions.